# Why is there a different deference return type when using std::reverse_iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, reverse-iterator

I'm trying to implement an iterator and a reverse iterator for a container, however, the return type of these two iterators are different.

Relevant code pertaining to the iterators:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
ActivePtr<T> ObjectPool<T, N>::ObjectPoolIterator::operator*()
{
    return curr->data[index].MakePtr();
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
typename ObjectPool<T, N>::ObjectPoolIterator ObjectPool<T, N>::begin() const
{
    return ObjectPoolIterator(head, nullptr, 0);
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
typename ObjectPool<T, N>::ObjectPoolIterator ObjectPool<T, N>::end() const
{
    return ObjectPoolIterator(nullptr, tail, 0);
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
std::reverse_iterator<typename ObjectPool<T, N>::ObjectPoolIterator> ObjectPool<T, N>::rbegin() const
{
    return std::make_reverse_iterator(end());
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
std::reverse_iterator<typename ObjectPool<T, N>::ObjectPoolIterator> ObjectPool<T, N>::rend() const
{
    return std::make_reverse_iterator(begin());
}
```

Relevant code pertaining to use case:

```
    for (ObjectPool<long long, 100000>::ObjectPoolIterator i = objectPool.begin(); i != objectPool.end(); ++i)
    {
        objectPool.Erase(*i); // works fine
    }

    for (std::reverse_iterator<ObjectPool<long long, 100000>::ObjectPoolIterator> i = objectPool.rbegin(); i != objectPool.rend(); ++i)
    {
        objectPool.Erase(*i); // error: unable to convert from long long to ActivePtr<long long>
    }
```

Sidenote: Unary * on an ActivePtr does return a T&. Maybe this might've affected the std::reverse_iterator's judgment on determining the return type?

Is there a workaround this besides defining my own reverse iterator?
I would like the reverse iterator to still return me an ActivePtr, just like the original iterator.
Thank you.

Comment: We don't have enough code to actually try finding the compile error - could you provide more, or create a minimal example of the issue?

Comment: Is `*i` returning an `ActivePtr` for std::reverse_iterator?

Comment: Well, given that a reverse iterator behaves differently than an iterator (i.e. incrementing it moves in reverse direction through elements of the container) there has to be some difference.   If you want them to be the same type, then the iterator will need to have a data member which specifies whether it is reversed or not, and every operation that changes the iterator (incrementing, etc) will need to check that.

Comment: [Mcve] is important because if you actually knew what code was relevant, you would understand the problem, which means you'd have the soluton.  And then have no need to ask here.  Minimal is important (delete or simplify code you think is unimportant), but so is complete (ensure you get the exact error message/problem after deleting/simplifying code).  I can make guesses (your iterator fails to be an iterator?) but they are guesses, and the effort to list every possible way your code could be wrong and describe it well enough that you could understand and verify is a waste of time.